# Finding all line segments lying inside polygon and what % of line inside polygon using Google Fusion Tables?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables

I was practicing with fusion tables sample code and while playing with some dataset, I was thinking how to achieve this. So if you see attached image.

Red blocks : These are SLA code or SLA areas. And if you click on it, will tell you total patients in that area having (COPD , Heart Disease, Lung cancer).

Yellow  lines : Boundary between different SLA regions.

Blue lines: Vic roads. When you click any line inside the red box. It will tell you road name, total vehicles.

Now, I want all the blue lines inside each red blocks basically I want total vehicles which is sum of all the vehicles on each blue line. I also want to find what % of whole blue line is lying in each red .

[image]